# Sheaf definition vs "Mayer Vietoris"

Tags: definition, sheaf-theory

Let $F$ be a presheaf on a space $X$ and say that $F$ has property MY if for all $U, V$ open in $X$ we have an exact sequence $$0 \to F(U \cup V) \to F(U) \oplus F(V) \to F(U \cap V)   $$

Is this property the same as the sheaf property ?

I think I can show it by recurrence.

Comment: Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up

Comment: No it is not equivalent because MY will only give information for finite covers and there are presheaves that satisfy MY (that is sheaf condition for finite covers) but not the sheaf conditions for infinite covers. Think about the presheaf of bounded function...